# Plural nouns that fit in the construction "to be all (plural noun)"

Tags: word-request, construction

I'm familiar with "to be all thumbs" and "to be all ears" but I recently came across "She was all smiles", which I thought was interesting.

I'm wondering whether there are other plural nouns usually used in this construction.

Comment: [*I'm all left feet*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22i%27m+all+left+feet%22) is another well-established variant. But to a first approximation, it's a "productive" construction, so lots of effectively one-off usages may have occurred.

Comment: [*I'm all butterflies*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22i%27m+all+butterflies%22&biw=1280&bih=635&tbm=bks&sxsrf=APwXEdct6srMdbMHivHAw77F1z3uOOBHQQ%3A1682638344354&ei=CAZLZJ-iFdmL9u8PrI-WsAk&ved=0ahUKEwifxrOmnMv-AhXZhf0HHayHBZYQ4dUDCAg&uact=5&oq=%22i%27m+all+butterflies%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEAM6BAghEApQiosBWLqqAWCFvQFoAHAAeACAAd0BiAHQDJIBBTYuNC4zmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-books)

Comment: All eyes, 'she is all legs', he (a man who gropes women or girls) is all hands, a clumsy person is all left feet, all mouth and no trousers (said my mother of boastful men).